# Am a newbie to PHP am doing a project where i need to direct $page_picture to an actual image url

Tags: php, image, show

All other parameters are echoing and the actual URL and the image is NOT displayed in the results page. I need a shortcut that will display the image itself.

Can I simply write:

```
$page_picture = ______( $some value['image.jpg'] );
```

So that `$page_picture` will display the image related to its associated URL?

All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this....

```
    echo  "<img src='".$page_picture."'>";
```

Assuming $page_picture is the url to your image, such as http://www.domain.com/img/blahblah.jpeg

If you wanna also link to the original image, when they click...

```
echo  "<a href='".$page_picture."' target=_blank><img src='".$page_picture."'></a>";
```